# Change prefix and numbering of section titles

Tags: section-titles

We have a document that is structured for example as follows:

1. Section

1.1 lorem

...

2. Section

2.1 lorem

...

Pos. 3

Pos. 3.1

Pos. 3.2

Pos. 3.3

Pos. 4

Pos. 5

3. Section

So I have to be free with the numbering and prefix. The positioning (Pos. XY) should display in the table of contents.

How does this work? Or does it at all?

Comment: Does the numbering of the "Pos" follow a certain numbering scheme, e.g. is there also a Pos 1?

Comment: No, it must be as flexible as possible. The answer of skyter ist totally satisfying. Thank you!

Comment: If my answer is totally satisfying, it would be nice, if you would confirm it :)

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know this.

Comment: Thanks! That is, why I told you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you could use the `\section*` and `\addcontentsline` command. Such as this:

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\section{Section}

\subsection{lorem}

\section{Section}

\subsection{lorem}

\section*{Pos. 3}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{Pos. 3}

\subsection*{Pos. 3.1}
\addcontentsline{toc}{subsection}{Pos. 3.1}

\section{Section}

\end{document}
```